# Open options page from content-script on button click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

I am trying to open my web-extension options page from an injected button via a content-script onto a page. Here is the setup:

**manifest setting:**

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options/options.html",
    "open_in_tab":true
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["icons/icon.png", "icons/icon64.png","options/options.html"]
```

**content-script.js:**

```
<a href="moz-extension://1f82d05-3abf-4bea-80e2-db87e97486d3/options/options.html" target="_blank">Settings</a>
```

What am I missing here? Also, I know `moz-extension:` might not be the best option for cross-browser operation but not sure what should be the correct namesapce?

**EDIT:**

I am using a fixed id in manifest as :

```
"applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "{adacfr40-acra-e2e1-8ccb-e01fd0e08bde}"
        }
},
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: See MDN article on web_accessible_resources - the UUID is random and you should use browser.runtime.getURL in your js code to get the real URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *content script*, as shown, is actually a chunk of HTML and not JavaScript, as expected. So it wouldn't work. Perhaps that's not your actual code, just what you create?

But suppose you do adjust the content script to add a button and have a listener attached (out of scope for this question, I think). How to open the options page?

The *canonical* way is to call [`browser.runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage), but that API [can't be called from a content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs).

Two options:

1. Stick with `openOptionsPage()`. In that case, you need a background (event) page that listens to Messaging, and then [signal from the content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) that you want the options page open.

   The advantage of this approach is that you *don't* need to make the options page web-accessible.
2. If you insist on directly opening the page from the content script / `a` tag, you can, but you'll need to get the dynamically-allocated UUID for your extension *instance*.

   The URL for your options page is not fixed, but should be obtained with `browser.runtime.getURL("options.html")`, and that URL should be used in the link creation.

   This method *requires* declaring it as web-accessible.

Comment: I am using a fixed id in manifest as : "applications": {
  "gecko": {
   "id": "{adacfr40-acra-e2e1-8ccb-e01fd0e08bde}"
  }
 },

Comment: Extension ID and UUID are different.

Comment: browser.runtime.getURL("options.html") worked :), Thanks

Comment: Trying to theme the Options page using this -  <link rel="stylesheet" href="material.min.css">
<script src="material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"> but this does not work? I even added all these files under web accessible.